# Convert text list into Dictionary?

Tags: list, dictionary, python-3.6

I have a list as the given one:

```
l = ['1,a','2,b','3,c']
```

I want to convert this list into a Dictionary, like this:

```
l_dict = {1:'a',2:'b',3:'c'}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: From your array. `l`. split `(,)` each element as `new ToElement` and assign it to a new object variable `l_dict` where key is `(ToElement[0])` and value `(ToElement[1])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to pass to the [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) constructor each string split by `','`

```
dict(e.split(',') for e in l)
```

output:

```
{'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to first split and then push the value to dict. Here there are two options if you just want to push it to dict you can use `list` else if you want in order use `od`

[Link](https://onlinegdb.com/r1RgLX5VL)

```
from collections import OrderedDict

l = ['1,a','2,b','3,c']

list = {}
od = OrderedDict() 

for text in l:
    convertToDict = text.split(",")
    list[convertToDict[0]] = convertToDict[1]
    od[convertToDict[0]] = convertToDict[1]


print(list)
print(od)
```